# Count number of Falses in 2d list until encountering True (Python)

Tags: python

I want to count the number of Falses in a nested list before there comes a True again. How do I do that? The number of Falses after a True is shown in the list `numoffalsescount`, which is then collected in the list `numoffalsescountlist`. The code inside the second if-statement has to be adjusted. Here is my code:

```python
def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = iterator.next()  # throws StopIteration if empty.
    for next in iterator:
        yield (prev,item,next)
        prev = item
        item = next
    yield (prev,item,None)

matrix2bool = [[True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True], [True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True], [False]]

i11 = 0
numoffalsescountlist = []
for index16 in matrix2bool:
    falsecount = 0
    falsecounttemp = 0
    falsecountmax = 0
    init = 0
    numoffalsescount = []
    for prev,item,next in neighborhood(matrix2bool[i11]):   
        if next == False:
            #print item, next
            if falsecount != 0:
                falsecount += 1
                falsecounttemp = falsecount
                #init = 0
                init += 1
                if falsecounttemp > falsecountmax:
                    falsecountmax = falsecounttemp
                print 'falsecount', falsecount
                print 'init', init
                print 'fcm', falsecountmax
                numoffalsescount.append(0)
                numoffalsescount[falsecount-init] = falsecountmax
                if falsecount != 0:
                    numoffalsescount[falsecount-1] = 0
            else:
                init += 1
                falsecount += 1
                falsecounttemp = falsecount
                falsecounttemp += falsecount - 1
                numoffalsescount.append(falsecounttemp)
        else:
            if falsecount != 0:
                falsecount = 0
                numoffalsescount.append(falsecount)
            else:
                x = 0
                numoffalsescount.append(0)
    print 'numoffalsescount', numoffalsescount
    i11 += 1
    numoffalsescountlist.append(numoffalsescount)
print 'numoffalsescountlist', numoffalsescountlist
```

The input list is `matrix2bool`, and should give the output:

```
numoffalsescount [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
numoffalsescount [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
numoffalsescount [0]
numoffalsescountlist [[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
```

But it gives me the output:

```
numoffalsescount [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0]
numoffalsescount [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
numoffalsescount [0]
numoffalsescountlist [[1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: You might consider cleaning up your example a bit.  There is a lot of superfluous structure in it--variables that aren't used or are unnecessary, for example.  Maybe also consider breaking it up into a couple smaller functions.  Don't be afraid to use underscores in variable names. For example, instead of `numoffalsecounts` consider just `false_counts`.  It already has "counts" in the name--the "num of" is superfluous.

Comment: I am willing to do that, but if there is an easier way to solve my question, I would like to know that.

Comment: Probably but I gave up reading your code.

Comment: @Iguananaut who cares about the code, the problem description is good enough. But I think the example solution is wrong and the first result should be `[1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]`...

Comment: While I think it's easy enough to provide an alternate solution (see below) this smacks a bit of a homework problem and rather than just tell them the answer I'd rather help suss out where the problem in their own code is.  But as written it's a bit impenetrable.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so sure about my interpretation of the question anymore - looking at the second example I would have thought the second element should have been a `1` too... should the result always be `0` for a `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply append `True` to each row and then calculate the index of the next `True` for every `True` element:

```
matrix = [[True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True],
          [True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True],
          [False]]

res = []
for row in matrix:
    rr = row + [True]
    row_res = [rr[n+1:].index(True) if rr[n] else 0
               for n in range(len(row) - 1)]
    res.append(row_res + [0])
```

For better readability, the same thing written without using a list comprehension and with some comments:

```
res = [] #our result list
for row in matrix:
    rr = row + [True]  #row with an extra True at the end so index always works
    row_res = []       #result for this row
    for n in range(len(row) - 1):
        #if x is True, calculate the relative index of the next true
        x = rr[n+1:].index(True) if rr[n] else 0
        row_res.append(x)
    row_res.append(0)  #add an extra 0 at the end for the last element
    res.append(row_res)
```

Comment: No my sample output is right: there have to be 2 zeros after the 2. It indicates there are 2 Falses after the True, not that there is a False after a boolean. Can you improve your code for me now?

Comment: @user1189952 so you only want the count if the element is `True`, and 0 for every `False`? The description is rather unclear in that regard, and no offense but i'm not going to read your code...